# option[selected=true] doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have this command (visibleSelect is jquery variable that holds multiple select list):

```
var selectedOption = visibleSelect.find('option[selected=true]');
```

From the watch window I can see that `selectedOption.length` is 0, but `visibleSelect.get(0)[1].selected` is `true`.

Why `selectedOption` doesn't containt the selected option? What is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using `visibleSelect.find("option").filter(":selected")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
var selectedOption = visibleSelect.find('option:selected');
```

Comment: +1 I'd better vote this up seeing as it's exactly the same as mine :)

Answer (score 4):

use `var selectedOption = visibleSelect.find('option:selected');`

Answer (score 2):

#### Description

The correct attribute value is `checked="checked"`. But Anyway you should use the jQuery `:selected` selector to guarantee cross browser compatility.

```
visibleSelect.find('option:selected');
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery :selected Selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)