# Show/Hide Div in JQuery for three select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, menu

```
                    <select name='main'>
                    <option value='For Sale'>For Sale</option>
                    <option value='Community'>Community</option>
                    </select>

                    <select name='sub'>
                    <option value='Animal'>Animal</option>
                    <option value='Fish'>Fish</option>
                    </select>

                    <select name='sub'>
                    <option value='Friend'>Friend</option>
                    <option value='Relitive'>Relitive</option>
                    </select>

                    <select name='sub2'>
                    <option value='Animal Thing'>Animal Thing</option>
                    <option value='Fish Thing'>Fish Thing</option>
                    </select>

                    <select name='sub'>
                    <option value='Best Friend'>Best Friend</option>
                    <option value='Relitive Home'>Relitive Home</option>
                    </select>
```

This is my html code and I want that when the user selects the main menu it will then show the sub menu and when the user selects the sub menu it will then show sub2 menu. I want to do this with Jquery, can someone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I would recommend that you revise and edit your question. As it is, it is currently it lacks sufficient information to offer you any assistance. Adding more details or a minimal example using [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co) will help us help you help yourself :) Best!

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing that the sub and sub2 classes are disabled / hidden?

You want to check if the user has selected a value in the main.
You can find this in the Jquery documentation [:selected Selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

So now you can see if you're `main` select was selected and then you can use this to enable to next select `sub`

If you want furthermore details on Selector, I think this question [How to check if an option is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213620/how-to-check-if-an-option-is-selected) has some solid answers.

Cheers!