# How to know that there is a option selected in select tag

Tags: jquery

I'm using .each iterating through all the options of the select tag and checking the condition If(this.selected)

This doesn't work for to get it done.

Comment: `$('#mySelect').val()`, also what do you mean by selected? Are you looking for the actual attribute? Because something is always selected.

Comment: edit your question give the full snippit of the code

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to check if an option is selected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213620/how-to-check-if-an-option-is-selected).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#select-id option").each(function() {
  if($(this).attr('selected')) {
    //your code for selected
  }
});
```