# How to select an ID in Jquery for an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use a form selector as shown, and depending on the option selected, a different output. Simple, yet I am not getting it to work. Here is what I have.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    if ("#1") {
        $("#display").html("<table width="221"><tbody><tr class="su-even"><td width="64"><strong>Level</strong></td><td width="64"><strong>Damage</strong></td><td width="93"><strong>Crown Tower Damage</strong></td></tr><tr><td width="64">1</td><td width="64">80</td><td width="93">32</td></tr></tbody></table>");
    } 
    if ("#2") {
        $("#display").html("<table width="221"><tbody><tr class="su-even"><td width="64"><strong>Level</strong></td><td width="64"><strong>Damage</strong></td><td width="93"><strong>Crown Tower Damage</strong></td></tr><tr><td width="64">2</td><td width="64">88</td><td width="93">36</td></tr></tbody></table>");
    }

});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div>
   <form id="option">
  <label for="level">Level at a glance:</label>
  <select name="level" id="level">
    <option id="1">1</option>
    <option id="2">2</option>

  </select>
</form>
<div id="display">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an option is selected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213620/how-to-check-if-an-option-is-selected)

Comment: You can't use only integer for id. Add something to it like 

    <option id="opt1">1</option>
    <option id="opt2">2</option>

and then check it with

    #opt1, #opt2

Comment: Not a duplicate, and that answer sadly was not a solution. Same result of nothing showing up.

Comment: Also, your script works on page load, you have to trigger it after something happened. Like onchange or onselect etc.

Comment: Valid point. I tried to add  $( "#level" ).select(function()  as well as $( "#option" ).select(function() {   both with and without the document onload. None of it is working. I can tell im close to this thing working, but just some simple things not allowing it to work yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple issues here.

- First of all, "#1" and "#2" are always going to == true, since they are strings.
- Second, the code that changes the text only happens once, on page load. There is nothing telling it to update after the menu is changed.
- Third, on the lines starting with `$("#display").html....`, you had what should have been a very long string, but you broke it up by using double quotes every time. You need to switch between single and double quotes. If I say, `"class="potato">"`, it sees `"class="` as one string, and `">"` as another, but it doesn't know what to do with `potato`. You need to use single quotes, like `"class='potato'>"` or `'class="potato">'`.

This is the fixed code:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>
function changeText(){
    if ($("#level option:selected").text() == "1") {
        $("#display").html("<table width='221'><tbody><tr class='su-even'><td width='64'><strong>Level</strong></td><td width='64'><strong>Damage</strong></td><td width='93'><strong>Crown Tower Damage</strong></td></tr><tr><td width='64'>1</td><td width='64'>80</td><td width='93'>32</td></tr></tbody></table>");
    } 
    if ($("#level option:selected").text() == "2") {
        $("#display").html("<table width='221'><tbody><tr class='su-even'><td width='64'><strong>Level</strong></td><td width='64'><strong>Damage</strong></td><td width='93'><strong>Crown Tower Damage</strong></td></tr><tr><td width='64'>2</td><td width='64'>88</td><td width='93'>36</td></tr></tbody></table>");
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    changeText();
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div>
   <form id="option">
  <label for="level">Level at a glance:</label>
  <select name="level" id="level" onchange="changeText()">
    <option id="1" >1</option>
    <option id="2">2</option>

  </select>
</form>
<div id="display">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is the only code I have so far been able to get to work. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript conditions are executed once, when the document is ready.
You have to add an event, when the select value change !

Add some values in your `option` elements ( `<option value="1">1</option>` )

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Set event
  $("#level").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() === "1") {
      $("#display").html(...);
    } else {
      $("#display").html(...);
    }
  }
  // Call event when document loaded
  $("#level").change();
});
```