# check one of the select box is selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

i have 4 selectbox ,first one is vehicle selectbox and other three are sub of that vehicle select box ,if i select vehicle select box and click button i want to show a error message ,because one of the sub select is also i want to selected .... any one help ..i am just beginner in jquery/javascript

[image]
in simplest words :p ..check one of the sub select box(cars , caravans,buses select box) is selected if i selected main vehicle selectbox...

my code :

```
 <div class="members-wrap-vehicle">
    <label>Vehicle</label>
    <select name="reservation[vehicle]">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <?php for($i=1;$i<11;$i++) { ?>
        <option <?php if($_POST['reservation']['vehicle'] == $i) { echo 'selected="selected"'; }?> value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
        <?php } ?>
   </select>
</div>

<div class="members-vehicle-list" <?php if($_POST['reservation']['vehicle'] == 0) { echo 'style="display: none;"'; } ?> >
    <div class="members-wrap-adult">
        <label>Cars</label>
        <select name="reservation[cars]">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            <?php for($i=1;$i<11;$i++) { ?>
            <option <?php if($_POST['reservation']['cars'] == $i) { echo 'selected="selected"'; }?> value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>

   <div class="members-wrap-child">
        <label>Caravans</label>
        <select name="reservation[caravans]">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            <?php for($i=1;$i<11;$i++) { ?>
            <option <?php if($_POST['reservation']['caravans'] == $i) { echo 'selected="selected"'; }?> value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="members-wrap-infant">
        <label>Buses</label>
        <select name="reservation[buses]">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
                <?php for($i=1;$i<5;$i++) { ?>
                <option <?php if($_POST['reservation']['buses'] == $i) { echo 'selected="selected"'; }?> value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?>                                     </option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
      </div>
```

Comment: Do you want immediate check when the vehicle is selected or after the search button is clicked ?

Comment: yes ,just need error alert or something like that suddenly....

Comment: When you say click the button, is this in regards to the search button? Basically you want validation on your form to ensure all sub-boxes are filled before submitting?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this SO question: [How to check if an option is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213620/how-to-check-if-an-option-is-selected)

Using what is suggested in that link, add an alert with whatever message you want if no option has been selected.

Answer (score 0):

This should work but there are some caveats.  You have to change your `<select>` element names to ids (id = 'xxx').  Also, this function assumes that the number of vehicles in the sub menus totals the number in the vehicles menu.  Please let me know if you need anything further! Cheers

```
$('#BUTTON_ID').on('click', function() {                 
    var vehicle = $('#reservation[vehicle]').val();
    var cars = $('#reservation[cars]').val();
    var caravans = $('#reservation[caravans]').val();
    var buses = $('#reservation[buses]').val();

    if (vehicle == (cars + caravans + buses)) {
       //do something
    } else {
       //error message
       alert('Error has occurred.');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are new lines of code but have certain changes for better understanding for you and test.

**HTML code**

```
<div class="members-wrap-vehicle">
     <label>Vehicle</label>
     <select name="reservation[vehicle]">
         <option value="0">Select</option>
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
     </select>
   </div>

   <div class="members-vehicle-list">
      <div class="members-wrap-adult">
         <label>Cars</label>
            <select name="reservation[cars]">
               <option value="0">Select</option>
               <option value="1">1</option>
               <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
         </div>

         <div class="members-wrap-child">
             <label>Caravans</label>
             <select name="reservation[caravans]">
                <option value="0">Select</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="members-wrap-infant">
           <label>Buses</label>
           <select name="reservation[buses]">
               <option value="0">Select</option>
               <option value="1">1</option>
               <option value="2">2</option>
          </select>
        </div>
   </div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$(function(){

     $('.members-wrap-vehicle select').change(function(){
         var cars = $('.members-wrap-adult select option:selected').val();
         var caravans = $('.members-wrap-child select option:selected').val();
         var buses = $('.members-wrap-infant select option:selected').val();

         if ( cars == 0 || caravans == 0 || buses == 0 ){
             alert('please select any of cars or caravans or buses');
      }

   });
});
```

Hope this works for you. THank YOu