# jQuery check what option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

If I have this code:

```
<td class="field-type">                  
     <select id="id_virtual_as_set-0-type" name="virtual_as_set-0-type">
       <option value="M">M</option>
       <option value="AI" selected="selected">AS I</option>
       <option value="D">D</option>
       <option value="P">P</option>
       <option value="A">A</option>
       <option value="R"</option>
     </select>      
</td>
```

And I wish to find out **which option value is selected**, how can I do this via jQuery? Also the issue is that I have a handle on the `<td>` element and I want to be able to access the `<select>` from the `<td>` element and then check what the selected option is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown

Comment: Or this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/10213645/4763754

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an option is selected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213620/how-to-check-if-an-option-is-selected)

Comment: Check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown

Comment: The issue is that this is a <td> element and I want to be able to access the <select> from the <td> element and then check what it's selected option is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Just try:

```
$("#id_virtual_as_set-0-type").val()
```

Comment: Please take the time to explain your answer rather than dump code. Here you can find more info on how to answer a question so other can profit from it as well: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Here, i have created an example of how to do this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
function getSelectedProperty(select){
var selectedOption = select.find("option:selected");
$("p").html("selected Value:"+selectedOption.val() + " SelectedText:" +selectedOption.html())
}
var select = $("select");
select.change(function(){
getSelectedProperty($(this));

});
getSelectedProperty(select);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="field-type">                  
     <select id="id_virtual_as_set-0-type" name="virtual_as_set-0-type">
       <option value="M">M</option>
       <option value="AI" selected="selected">AS I</option>
       <option value="D">D</option>
       <option value="P">P</option>
       <option value="A">A</option>
       <option value="R"</option>
     </select>      
     
     <p></p>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's many way to do it.
And this is how I do

```
$('select').on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).find('option:selected').val());
});
```