# Change text on button click when a certain element from a dropdown is selected

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to change the text on the button click when a certain element from the list is selected. For ex: when element "address" is selected from the list I want to press the button and change the text accordingly.
Down below is the code I got but it's not working. It's only generating names and not addresses.

HTML:

```
<p id="generated-text">
Waiting... Just select something right here
</p>
```

```
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="select">
      <span>Select</span>

    </div>
    <input type="hidden">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li id="address">Address</li>
      <li id="name">Name</li>
    </ul>
   </div>

   <span class="msg"></span>
  </div>

  <a href="#" id="trigger" onclick="random()" title="Generate new 
  content" class="generate-btn">RANDOMIZE</a>
```

JS:

```
 /*Dropdown Menu*/
  $('.dropdown').click(function () {
    $(this).attr('tabindex', 1).focus();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle(300);
});
$('.dropdown').focusout(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').slideUp(300);
});
$('.dropdown .dropdown-menu li').click(function () {
    $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('span').text($(this).text());
    $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('input').attr('value', 
$(this).attr('id'));
});
/*End Dropdown Menu*/


  if (document.getElementById("address").selected = true) {


    function random() {

    var address = new Array();
    address[1] = "709 Honey Creek Dr.New York, NY 10028";
    address[2] = "73 Pacific St.Forest Hills, NY 11375";
    address[3] = "812 Thatcher Court Yonkers, NY 10701";
    address[4] = "3 South Sherman Street Astoria, NY 11106";
    address[5] = "15 St Margarets Lane New York, NY 10033";

    var rdmAddresses = Math.floor(Math.random()*address.length);
    $('#generated-text').html(address[rdmAddresses]);


    }

  }


  if (document.getElementById("name").selected = true) {


    function random() {

    var name = new Array();
    name[1] = "Name 1";
    name[2] = "Name 2";
    name[3] = "Name 3";
    name[4] = "Name 4";
    name[5] = "Name 5";

    var rdmNames = Math.floor(Math.random()*name.length);
    $('#generated-text').html(name[rdmNames]);


    }



  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

- as done so the if blocks are evaluated only once
- testing of values is done by `==` or `===` (stricter), `=` is assignment, so inside the conditions you're assigning, result of which is the value you are assigning (`true` in this case)
- you cannot have more functions of the same name
- the elements get by `document.getElementById("address")` doesn't have `selected` property (btw `selected` is unique to the `select` element; see [How to check if an option is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10213620/8555393)
  )
- even if they had it, you aren't assigning/changing it anywhere

I propose these updates:

- introduce one `random` function which will call the two randomizers according to what is selected
- as you are already storing which item is selected inside the the hidden input, add it an id and inside the conditions test against it's value instead of messing with the `selected` property/attribute

HTML changes:

```
<input id="selected" type="hidden">
```

JavaScript changes:

```
function random() {
    var selected = document.getElementById("selected").value;
    console.log('selected:', selected);

    if (selected === 'address')
        randomAddress();
    else if (selected === 'name')
        randomName();
}

function randomAddress() {
    var address = new Array();
    address[1] = "709 Honey Creek Dr.New York, NY 10028";
    address[2] = "73 Pacific St.Forest Hills, NY 11375";
    address[3] = "812 Thatcher Court Yonkers, NY 10701";
    address[4] = "3 South Sherman Street Astoria, NY 11106";
    address[5] = "15 St Margarets Lane New York, NY 10033";

    var rdmAddresses = Math.floor(Math.random()*address.length);
    $('#generated-text').html(address[rdmAddresses]);
}

function randomName() {
    var name = new Array();
    name[1] = "Name 1";
    name[2] = "Name 2";
    name[3] = "Name 3";
    name[4] = "Name 4";
    name[5] = "Name 5";

    var rdmNames = Math.floor(Math.random()*name.length);
    $('#generated-text').html(name[rdmNames]);
}
```

It would be even better to return just a resulting string from the randomizers and assign the html of the `#generated-text` inside the `random()` function so you have the logic connected with the elements on one place (i.e. the less side-effects scattered through the code the better):

```
function random() {
    var selected = document.getElementById("selected").value;
    var text = 'nothing selected';

    if (selected === 'address')
        text = getRandomAddress();
    else if (selected === 'name')
        text = getRandomName();

    $('#generated-text').html(text);
}

function getRandromAddress() {
    //...
    //$('#generated-text').html(name[rdmNames]);
    return name[rdmNames];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tomas! Very well explained :) It was my very first attempt with a dropdown